# How to install R packets on a Shiny Server with Kubernetes?

Tags: r, ubuntu, kubernetes, dockerfile, shiny-server

I'm trying to publish some panels on Shiny Server with Kubernetes, but I'm struggling with R packets that are not installed on the server.The panels are working on my test environment on AWS (without K8s). The error is below detailed.

```
> su: ignoring --preserve-environment, it’s mutually exclusive with --login
> Error in library(“shinyWidgets”) :
>  there is no package called ‘shinyWidgets’
> Calls: runApp ... sourceUTF8 -> eval -> eval -> ..stacktraceon.. -> library
> Execution halted
```

As commented in the code, many alternative options to install the R packets were tried without success.

```
FROM rocker/shiny-verse:latest
USER root

# Finding required libraries. Libraries should be installed in /usr/share/doc
# pak::pkg_system_requirements(“dplyr”, “ubuntu”, “20.04")
# Packects should be installed in /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
# Install system requirements for index.R as needed

RUN apt-get update -qq \
 && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
   gdal-bin \
   gsfonts \
   imagemagick \
   libavfilter-dev \
   libcurl4-openssl-dev \
   libgdal-dev \
   libgeos-dev \
   libicu-dev \
   libjq-dev \
   libmagick++-dev \
   libnode-dev \
   libpng-dev \
   libproj-dev \
   libprotobuf-dev \
   libsqlite3-dev \
   libssl-dev \
   libudunits2-dev \
   make \
   protobuf-compiler \
   zlib1g-dev \
   lbzip2 \
   libgeos-c1v5 \
   libxml2-dev \
   sudo \
   pandoc \
   pandoc-citeproc \
   libcairo2-dev \
   libxt-dev \
   libssh2-1-dev \
   littler \
   proj-bin

# Install Tree
RUN apt-get install -y tree

RUN install2.r --error --deps TRUE \
    data.table \
    dplyr \
    geobr \
    rgeos \
    geojsonio \
    ggplot2 \
    ggrepel \
    ggthemes \
    grid \
    magick \
    magrittr \
    pak \
    plotly \
    png \
    readr \
    rmapshaper \
    shinyBS \
    shinycssloaders \
    shinyWidgets \
    sp \
    && rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages

# I also tried to install using these packages with either no success.
# install R packages required
# RUN R -e “install.packages(‘shinyWidgets’, repos=‘http://cran.rstudio.com/’)”
# RUN R -q -e ‘pak::local_install(“shinyWidgets”)’

## assume shiny app is in build folder /shiny
COPY ./cenarios/* /srv/shiny-server/
COPY ./log/shiny-server/ /var/log/shiny-server/

# USER shiny
# allow permission
# RUN sudo chown -R shiny:shiny /srv/shiny-server
# run app
CMD [“/usr/bin/shiny-server”]
```